# laravel err Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::whereBetween() must be of the type array

Tags: php, html, laravel

i am new in laravel this is my first app well,

i want to display all operations between 2 dates insert by user but i got this error(Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::whereBetween() must be of the type array, null given, called in C:\Users\tgtv\Desktop)

operation table (id , vehicule , date, personnel_id)

okay now this is my search blade php

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('etatperso.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" width="20" height="20">

    @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
                 <label class="col-md-4">Personnel :</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                <select name="personnel_id"  id="personnel_id" class="form-control" >
                    <option value="">Select Personnel</option>
                    @foreach($personnels as $personnel)
                    <option value="{{ $personnel->id}}">{{ $personnel->nom }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
                </div>
            </div>


         <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4">Date debut :</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="date_debut"   name="date_fin" value="{{ old('date', date('Y-m-d')) }}" class="form-control input-lg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    


    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4">Date fin</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="date_fin"   name="date_fin" value="{{ old('date', date('Y-m-d')) }}" class="form-control input-lg" />
        </div>
    </div>   
    
     <br/>
    <div class="form-group text-center">
        <input type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-primary input-lg" value="Ajouter Personnel" />
    </div>

</form>
```

and this is my function search in the controller

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $personnels = Personnel::all();
        $personnel_id=$request->get('personnel_id');
         $date_debut=$request->get('date_debut');
        $date_fin=$request->get('date_fin');
        $data =Operation::where('personnel_id','LIKE',$personnel_id)->whereBetween('date',$date_debut,$date_fin)->paginate(1000);


        return view('etatperso.resultat', compact('data','personnels'));





    }
```

and finnaly this is my result.blade.php

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <th width="10%">ID</th>
        <th width="10%">Vehicule</th>
        <th width="10%">Personnel</th>
        <th width="10%">Creation</th>
        <th width="10%">Description</th>
        <th width="10%">Date</th>
        <th width="10%">Etat</th>
        <th width="10%">Prix total</th>
        

    </tr>
    @foreach($data as $row)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $row->id}}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->vehicule }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->personnel->nom}}</td>
            <td> {{$row->creation}}</td>        
            <td>{{ $row->description }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->created_at}}</td>

            @if($row->etat =="en cours")
                <td style="background-color: red;">{{ $row->etat}}</td>
                @elseif($row->etat =="paye")
                
                <td style="background-color: green;">{{ $row->etat}}</td>

                @endif
            <td>{{ $row->prix_total}}</td>
            
            
                @if($row->etat =="paye")
                <td>
                    <a href="{{ route('details', $row->id) }}" style="display: none;" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Ajouter articles nécessaire</a>
                
                <br> </br>  
                <a href="{{ route('liste_utilisee', $row->id) }}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Liste des Articles Utilisés</a></td>
                @elseif ($row->etat =="en cours")
                <td>
                    <a href="{{ route('details', $row->id) }}"  class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Ajouter articles nécessaire</a>
                
                <br> </br>

                <a href="{{ route('action', $row->id) }}"  class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Ajouter action</a> 
                <br> </br>
                <a href="{{ route('liste_utilisee', $row->id) }}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Liste des Articles Utilisés</a></td>

        
        </tr>
        @endif
    @endforeach

</table>
```

Comment: you only need to use it like the following Operation::where('personnel_id','LIKE',$personnel_id)->whereBetween('date',[$date_debut,$date_fin])->paginate(1000);

Comment: the error is gone but .... it dosent display anything ......:(

Comment: Then make sure of the data in the db if they are existed between the 2 dates or not and also make sure of the format of the dates.

Comment: aa when i use dd in $date_debut it return null .... but i get the request i think :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WhereBetween second parameter must be in array.
In your code
change this

```
$data =Operation::where('personnel_id','LIKE',$personnel_id)->whereBetween('date',$date_debut,$date_fin)->paginate(1000);
```

to

```
$data =Operation::where('personnel_id','LIKE',$personnel_id)->whereBetween('date',[$date_debut,$date_fin])->paginate(1000);
```

**UPDATE**

also change this

```
<input type="date_debut"   name="date_fin" value="{{ old('date', date('Y-m-d')) }}" class="form-control input-lg" />
```

to

```
<input type="date_debut"   name="date_debut" value="{{ old('date', date('Y-m-d')) }}" class="form-control input-lg" />
```

Comment: the error is gone but .... it dosent display anything ......:(

Comment: is it displaying a blank white screen?

Comment: its displaying my result page but its empty 
if i remove whereBetween('date',[$date_debut,$date_fin])  so its work normalyy and display operation

Comment: Maybe there's no record between $date_debut and $date_fin in the database ?

Comment: aa when i use dd in $date_debut it return null .... but i get the request i think :/

Comment: @Hassen I think there's a mistake in your input, the name is supposed to be date_debut but it is date_fin. I updated my answer, please take a look.

Comment: ohh yeah thats true its working now thank u my friend :))))

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 $data =Operation::where('personnel_id','LIKE',$personnel_id)->whereBetween('date',[$date_debut,$date_fin])->paginate(1000);
```

Comment: the error is gone but ....   it dosent display anything ......:(

Comment: If you debug with dd($data); anything is displayed ?

Comment: no data i think 
LengthAwarePaginator {#513 ▼
  #total: 0
  #lastPage: 1
  #items: Collection {#501 ▼
    #items: []
  }
  #perPage: 1000
  #currentPage: 1
  #path: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/consultant/etatperso"
  #query: []
  #fragment: null
  #pageName: "page"
  +onEachSide: 3
  #options: array:2 [▼
    "path" => "http://127.0.0.1:8000/consultant/etatperso"
    "pageName" => "page"
  ]
}